# Historical NWS GFS forecast data

Tags: weather

The National Weather Service (NWS) makes the results from its Global Forecast System model (GFS) available for download as GRIB2 files.

While accessing current (or recent) forecasts is straight-forward, I am looking for the archived forecasts over at least the last year, better multiple years back for the purpose of statistical analysis of predominant weather patterns in certain areas.

Does anybody know how to access this information?

Comment: Just coming across this question years later as I have same issue. Were you ever able to solve this? If so, I would love to know how you did it. I am loking for historical GFS forecasts myself.

Answer (score 3):

Have you google it ?

Is this what you wanted ?

https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs